# What's the fastest way to raise DPS to 20k as Barbarian

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

I'm a barbarian in Inferno and struggle with my damage-output. Currently I'm at 11k DPS but I'd really love to have 16-25k. My weapon is a 1-hand axe with 720 DPS (the best one I could afford).

What (affordable) equipment will boost my DPS the most/what stats am I looking for?

Comment: If you can afford it, get accessories (rings, amulets) with the +damage modifier (e.g., +4-8 damage). The +damage is multiplicative (applied before your you calculate the bonus from your primary stat) so even a little can mean a 100-300 dps increase.

Comment: You need to get a better weapon for inferno.

Comment: spend £50 on the real money auction house

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to get a serious boost would be to get a competitive one-hander to use in the offhand, or a two-hander - the problem with that being, of course, that Barbarians in Inferno are already in serious trouble *with* a shield, even with a load of armor and resists.

The biggest damage booster out there, then (aside from stacking tons of extra strength), would be items with attack speed - *by far* the most powerful stat when you have a high DPS weapon. Gloves, rings, and amulets are the most common (not sure if they're the only) places to find it.

Substantial amounts of +crit and +crit damage are a little harder to find on otherwise good items, but with the Barbarian's mechanics and passives, they may well pay off.

Answer (score 4):

There are many things you can do to boost your DPS:

1. **Consider a 2 handed weapon:** While sacraficing defense you can boost your base DPS by a significant amount. Luckily, if you find a weapon with high damage, and some vitality you may be able to counteract the lack of defense a bit. Lifesteal/life per kill doesn't hurt either.
2. **Find a shield that boosts DPS:** If you're set on a one hander, look for a shield that adds to your strength in order to boost your damage output a bit. A shield can be very defensive and also have offensive properties.
3. **Use gems wisely:** This may be an obvious one, but put Rubies in your weapon sockets to boost the overall DPS of the weapon you are using.
4. **Dual wield:** The same concept for 2 handers applies here. Increase your damage output significantly by sacraficing some defense.
5. **Use your skills:** There are certain skills such as the passive [Brawler](http://www.diablowiki.net/Brawler) that can increase your DPS in specific situations. Study your skills and your runes and find a nice balance of crit chance, damage and defense.

Comment: I must note that at high levels (Inferno), rubies in weapons are far outclassed by emeralds. When you already have hundreds of base weapon damage, getting a big crit multiplier helps far more than a few dozen extra base damage.

Comment: @Hyppy Good point, plus the increased crit chance from some spells. Could defintley increase DPS significantly.

Comment: Bear in mind that for 2h weapons, the attack speed drops, which cuts into your crits and per-hit effects/bonuses. I found a tempting 2-hander which was double the DPS as my 1 hander, but I could never get the fury up to speed, I stunned fewer enemies, and my survivability dropped. By way of example, In this scenario, some of the brutish big guys with knockbacks get stunned so much they barely touch you, but if you reduce the number of hits, the 15 percent chance of stun (or whatever it is) isn't enough to interrupt them. (I'm not saying this is a good Inferno stat, just consider the downside)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about your follower you can do a lot to boost her overall dps which is a boost to yours. Also you need to remember that weapon dps is the biggest increase to your overall dps. It sucks but a higher dps weapon is the way to go. And then the higher your weapon damage the more the other stats effect your dps.

Answer (score -2):

You should farm gold until you have around 150k then find two 1 handed weapons with high Strength/Vitality/Increased attack speed. For example, each of my one handed weapons I use have more than 180 strength on it. Also fill your inventory with strength charms (followers) whichever they are